# Vite with Redoc Left Panel Missing

Tags: vite, redoc

I'm developing an React application with vite and redoc. For some reason the left panel with the quick links is just not appearing when I generate the spec. I've verified it isn't the specs. Imaged demonstrating the expected versus actual behavior is below. Any idea why the left panel could be missing?

Relevant dependencies in package.json:

```
"@mui/material": "^5.11.12",
"core-js": "^3.31.1",
"mobx": "^6.3.2",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
"redoc": "^2.0.0-rc.72",
"styled-components": "^5.3.5",
"vite-plugin-node-polyfills": "^0.9.0"
```

My vite.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint';
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    manifest: true,
  },
  plugins: [react(), eslint(), nodePolyfills({ globals: { process: true }, protocolImports: true })],
});
```

[image: Expectation]

[image: Reality]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a painstaking few days, finally got this working.

When running `npm install redoc`, one of its dependencies `mobx-react^7.2.0` was automatically installed. My organization's private npm repository's latest `mobx-react` version is `7.2.1`. Turns out `mobx@7.2.1` is incompatible with this version of redoc (which shouldn't have been the case, but maybe there's been an update since then) but `mobx@7.6.0` is compatible.

Moral of the story, try downloading from a public registry to see if something works, and narrow down the broken dependency structure from there!